# AngularJS - Using Nested JSON Objects in Sum of NG-Repeat totals

Tags: angularjs

I have adapted some code from an answer to a similar question I found searching here. Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to fix this code...

I am trying to to sum the values of a filtered column in ng-repeat. It works great for the first level of nested JSON but will not work on the second level..

The JSON provided is just an example..The real JSON is coming from a source that I have no control over the structure of the JSON itself.

My code is below..Help Please!!!

```js
       

angular.module("turfApp", [])
            .filter('sumOfValue', function () {
                return function (data, key) {
                    debugger;
                    if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(key))
                        return 0;
                    var sum = 0;

                    angular.forEach(data, function (v,k) {
                        sum = sum + parseInt(v[key]);
                    });
                    return sum;
                }
            }).controller("turfController", function ($scope) {
                $scope.items = [{
                    "id": { "t": 1 }, //NESTED "T" VALUE WILL NOT COMPUTE IN TOTALS
                    "details": "test11",
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "price": 100
                }, {
                    "id": { "t": 2 }, //NESTED "T" VALUE WILL NOT COMPUTE IN TOTALS
                    "details": "test12",
                    "quantity": 5,
                    "price": 120
                }, {
                    "id": { "t": 3 }, //NESTED "T" VALUE WILL NOT COMPUTE IN TOTALS
                    "details": "test3",
                    "quantity": 6,
                    "price": 170
                }, {
                    "id": { "t": 4 }, //NESTED "T" VALUE WILL NOT COMPUTE IN TOTALS
                    "details": "test3",
                    "quantity": 8,
                    "price": 70
                }, {
                    "id": { "t": 5 }, //NESTED "T" VALUE WILL NOT COMPUTE IN TOTALS
                    "details": "test5",
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "price": 160
                }, {
                    "id": { "t": 6 }, //NESTED "T" VALUE WILL NOT COMPUTE IN TOTALS
                    "details": "test6",
                    "quantity": 9,
                    "price": 100
                }]
            });
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>   

<div ng-app="turfApp" ng-controller="turfController">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchFilter.id.t" placeholder="Search by ID" />
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Details</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in resultValue=(items | filter:searchFilter)">
                    <td><p>{{item.id.t}}</p></td>
                    <td><p>{{item.details}}</p></td>
                    <td><p>{{item.quantity}}</p></td>
                    <td><p>{{item.price}}</p></td>
                    <td><p>{{item.quantity * item.price}}</p></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div>
            <h4>Sum ID -- {{resultValue | sumOfValue:'id.t'}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>Sum Quanitity -- {{resultValue | sumOfValue:'quantity'}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the way you pass the `'id.t'` in:

```
  <h4>Sum ID -- {{resultValue | sumOfValue:'id.t'}}</h4>
```

This way the filter `sumOfValue` will try to get the value of `parseInt(v['id.t'])` which is **undefined** always! resulting in the `NaN` that you are seeing.

To fix this, you need to update your `sumOfValue` filter to read the proper value in the nested json, as shown in the following example:

```js
angular.module("turfApp", [])
  .filter('sumOfValue', function() {
    return function(data, key, innerKey) {
      debugger;
      if (angular.isUndefined(data) || angular.isUndefined(key))
        return 0;
      var sum = 0;

      angular.forEach(data, function(v, k) {
        if (innerKey) {
           sum = sum + parseInt(v[key][innerKey]);
        } else {
           sum = sum + parseInt(v[key]);
        }
      });
      return sum;
    }
  }).controller("turfController", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      "id": {
        "t": 1
      }, //NESTED "T" VALUE WILL NOT COMPUTE IN TOTALS
      "details": "test11",
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": 100
    }, {
      "id": {
        "t": 2
      }, //NESTED "T" VALUE WILL NOT COMPUTE IN TOTALS
      "details": "test12",
      "quantity": 5,
      "price": 120
    }, {
      "id": {
        "t": 3
      }, //NESTED "T" VALUE WILL NOT COMPUTE IN TOTALS
      "details": "test3",
      "quantity": 6,
      "price": 170
    }, {
      "id": {
        "t": 4
      }, //NESTED "T" VALUE WILL NOT COMPUTE IN TOTALS
      "details": "test3",
      "quantity": 8,
      "price": 70
    }, {
      "id": {
        "t": 5
      }, //NESTED "T" VALUE WILL NOT COMPUTE IN TOTALS
      "details": "test5",
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": 160
    }, {
      "id": {
        "t": 6
      }, //NESTED "T" VALUE WILL NOT COMPUTE IN TOTALS
      "details": "test6",
      "quantity": 9,
      "price": 100
    }]
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="turfApp" ng-controller="turfController">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchFilter.id.t" placeholder="Search by ID" />
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in resultValue=(items | filter:searchFilter)">
        <td>
          <p>{{item.id.t}}</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>{{item.details}}</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>{{item.quantity}}</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>{{item.price}}</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>{{item.quantity * item.price}}</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div>
    <h4>Sum ID -- {{resultValue | sumOfValue:'id':'t'}}</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Sum Quanitity -- {{resultValue | sumOfValue:'quantity'}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm am very new to the coding world and I'm so thankful for people such as yourself who are willing to help with their time and be so thorough. Thank you again!